# consider if given vectors are elements of the span?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vectors **u** = (1,3,2) and **v** = (2,-1,1) in ℝ³.

Determine whether or not (1,7,5) ∈ span(**u**,**v**)
.

Not really sure what to do, I was thinking of checking to see if **u** and **v** span ℝ³ and then the given vector would be an element of the span? Also to check the span should I find linear combinations other than the trivial solution?

Comment: Two vectors cannot possibly span $\Bbb R^3$: $\dim\Bbb R^3=3$. All you need to do is see whether there are scalars $a$ and $b$ such that $a\mathbf{u}+b\mathbf{v}=(1,7,5)$. That’s just a matter of checking whether a certain system of linear equations has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking of checking to see if $\bf u$ and $\bf v$ span ℝ³ and then the given vector would be an element of the span?

Note that ${\bf u}$ and $\bf v$ can never span $\Bbb R^3$ alone, you need at least three vectors to do that. I think you meant to check if $(1,7,5), {\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}$ together span $\Bbb R^3$. This is indeed a good strategy: if they do span $\Bbb R^3$, they are linearly independent, and so $ (1,7,5)$ can't be spanned by $\bf u$ and $\bf v$.

If you put the vectors's components in columns (or rows, whatever) of a matrix and compute the determinant of that matrix, you'll get the volume of the paralelepiped formed by the three vectors. If $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\text{the determinant}}$ the volume is zero, the three vectors are coplanar, hence one of them is a linear combination of the others. Meaning: look at $$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 3 & 2 \\2 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 7 & 5\end{vmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\mathbf{w}=(1,7,5)$ is in $\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{\mathbf{u}=(1,3,2),\mathbf{v}=(2,-1,1)\}$ if and only if there exist $a,b\in\Bbb R$ such that
$$
a\cdot\mathbf{u}+b\cdot\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{w}\tag{1}
$$
But (1) holds if and only if
$$
\begin{array}{rcrcr}
a  & + & 2b  & = & 1 \\
3a & - & b & = & 7 \\
2a & + & b & = & 5
\end{array}\tag{2}
$$
Now, note that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2  & 1 \\
3 & -2 & 7 \\
2 & 1  & 5
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}
$$
Finally, (3) implies the system (2) is inconsistent which implies (1) does not hold.